# Create Java Annotation to replace a token with code

Tags: java, eclipse, macros, annotations

I'm doing a project which in essence is a way for a user to create macros for very long/repetitive code so they can then put these macros into a their code to increase readability and encourage re-usability.

The project is split up into two areas: an RCP application where the user constructs their macros and saves them to file, and a plugin-in in eclipse where a user can insert a macro.

The RCP application has come along nicely, but now I'm getting to the real bit where I want java to look at a piece of code and at compile time go 'Oh, that piece of code means this'.

For example a user could have created a macro with an identifier `macro1` that represents the code `System.out.println("Hello World");`. They want to use it in their class `foo` which will look like:

```
class foo{

    //lots of java....

    macro1

    //lots more java
}
```

I want the user to run their class, and when Java compiles it replace `macro1` with it's value.

I have been looking into this for a while and read up a little bit on JavaCC and looked into Ants Replace Task but I feel I want to go down the road of creating a custom annotation to inform Java that this string below the annotation should be transformed into/replaced by a piece of java code located in a specific text file. Hopefully ending up with something like:

```
@ExpandMacro
macro1
```

To me it seems like it could be possible but I don't know if I'm just being too optimistic! :)

Also one of my concerns is how deployable would it be as a plugin? If I create a custom annotation how would I make it available to the user to use?

Any advice/insights would be very helpful!

**Edit:** I have also looked into [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) which is looks extremely insteresting. But again I'm concerned about deployability because of the amount of setup required for a lombok project.

Comment: Are you looking to insert java code (repeated code, or as you call it macro1) into arbitrary places? Or more like, call this macro before/after you run function X?  Because I'm wondering if AspectJ could help here...

Comment: Can you use Code Templates in eclipse? http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-add-your-own-code-template-in-eclipse.html

Comment: @user1766760 Yes I'm looking to insert these macros into arbitrary places to represent some predefined code that can be located in a text file.

Comment: @Rohit Code Templates are nice but I don't see how they could help me in this situation? Can you populate code templates with text from a file programmatically?

Comment: May be I did not understand your use case clearly. So you have a Java class which needs to load code from another file ( represented by a macro) at compile time. If this is correct, how different is this from using another java file?

I guess I do not understand this two step process where a person writes code, assigns a name and needs to be automatically detected and compiled with some other code where the name is specified.

Comment: @Rohit Its similar to what you say but think of the macro (in this example 'macro1') being a token to represent a piece of code, at runtime java will see the annotation above macro1 and then translate it into its actual value so it can be compiled into the class file; this way the java file will remain the same and keep the syntactic sugar element I desire (I.e.the java file will still have the macros instead of fully expanded code). How would you suggest loading it in from another java file?

Comment: I would split the code base into separate files, even in separate jars if required and replace the jar when stuff changes. I am guessing this is some contract between this macro and your code that includes it. This is really just calling a method in another class which is in a separate file and/or jar.

If you want to transparently do something before/after the macro/code, you should look at Aspect Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for doing this is Annotation Processor (something like Lombokg). With JSR 269 Pluggable Annotation Processing API configuration is easy, because jar with processor is autodiscovered.

Look at: http://www.slideshare.net/PolymathicCoder/the-art-of-metaprogramming-in-java page 34

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean because I don't fully understand? Do you mean I can package to Annotation Processor as a jar and all the user would have to do is include it in the class path?

Comment: Sorry, after reading your question again I think Annotation Processor is not best for you.

Comment: But, you can create annotation like 

@ExpandMacro, and this will work also, but I think it is not the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this differently. I think better for you is to use dynamic language (groovy for example). You can write code in Java and run it dynamically with Groovy (without compilation) - because java code is compatible with groovy. So you can simple replace macro1 with what you need and run this code. With groovy you can

- write code than looks like java
- replace macros with real code
- run code without compilation

Links to read:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java